# Make gorm add value if exists and ignore it if no value on insert to db

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am writing an API using go and gorm . I have a column in my db - call_id , that is a foreign key.But it is nullable(meaning it accepts null as a value). I have a struct that am using to create a survey response, and it has CallID as one of its fields. I want to be able to create a survey response whether or not the struct has call_id or not(it is not required on the json and it is nullable). But when I attempt to ommit call_id from my payload, it is given a default value of 0, which is not accepted in the db since it is a foreign key.
`ERROR: insert or update on table "survey_responses" violates foreign key constraint "survey_responses_call_id_fkey" (SQLSTATE 23503) INSERT INTO "survey_responses" ("survey_question_id","answer","contact_id","created_at","updated_at","call_id") VALUES (34,'1000',26,'2023-11-09 13:54:58.221','2023-11-09 13:54:58.221',0)`

**This is my models**

```
type SurveyResponses struct {
ID               uint      `json:"id" gorm:"column:id"`
SurveyQuestionID uint      `json:"survey_question_id" gorm:"column:survey_question_id" binding:"required"`
Response         string    `json:"answer" gorm:"column:answer" binding:"required"`
ContactID        uint      `json:"contact_id" gorm:"column:contact_id" binding:"required"`
CreatedAt        time.Time `json:"created_at" gorm:"column:created_at;autoCreateTime"`
UpdatedAt        time.Time `json:"updated_at" gorm:"column:updated_at;autoUpdateTime"`
CallID           uint      `json:"call_id" gorm:"column:call_id"`}
```

This is my api

```
func SubmitSurveyResponses(ctx *gin.Context) {
responses := []models.SurveyResponses{}
if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&responses); err != nil {
    if invalid, err := utils.ModelValidationResponse(err); err == nil {
        ctx.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, invalid)
        return
    }
    logrus.Error(err)
    ctx.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"errors": []string{err.Error()}})
    return
}

// for i, response := range responses {
//  if response.CallID == 0 {
//      responses[i].CallID = 1
//  }
// }

err := models.SurveyResponsesSaveBatch(&responses)
if err != nil {
    logrus.Error(err)
    ctx.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"errors": []string{err.Error()}})
    return
}
ctx.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusCreated, responses)
```

}

I have tried forcing nil(since the field accepts a null value) before this line like this. But I get(cannot use nil as uint value in assignment). I need help with this.

```
for i, response := range responses {
    if response.CallID == 0 {
        responses[i].CallID = nil
    }
}

err := models.SurveyResponsesSaveBatch(&responses)
```

Comment: I dont understand GoLang too much, but looks like its not accepting null. You may put * before the `uint` in CallID row.

"CallID           *uint      `json:"call_id" gorm:"column:call_id"`"

give it a try.

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick . Could you explain it further ?

Comment: I am happy to hear that. I really cant explain. I am new at go. I just know `* allows to assign nil`.